# Working with Car and CarMechanic classes together, can't seem to change object's members?

Tags: c++, class

So, I have two classes: Car and CarMechanic. I have declared car broken using  a function of car, for the repair man to then repair it. Then I wanted the repairMan to also change the oil, to highest quality I decided would be 5 (and lowest is 1). Then I need to spray paint the car. My problem is, while repairing the car works, changing the oil and spraying the car does not. It seems like inside the function for it of the Car Mechanic's, it does set it using the set function for that variable, but then it reverses back upon exiting this function.

I am really unsure why it does this, especially since it seems to work for when the car is broken down. I tried checking over it, so if it is something stupid again, I'm sorry for wasting your time.

CarMechanic.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Car.h"
using namespace std;
class CarMechanic
{
private:
string name;
public:
CarMechanic(string name); //constructor
~CarMechanic();
//class member function prototypes
void repairCar(Car &carToFix);
void oilChange(Car carToOil);
void resprayCar(Car carToSpray, string sprayColour); 
};
```

CarMechanic.cpp:

```
#include "CarMechanic.h"
#include <iostream>

CarMechanic::CarMechanic(string name)       //constructor
{}

CarMechanic::~CarMechanic() {} //destructor does nothing

void CarMechanic::repairCar(Car &carToFix)
{   
carToFix.setBrokenDown(false);   //we are setting the brokenDown private 
member to false for that car, so that it gets fixed!
std::cout << "I have repaired your car." << std::endl;
}

void CarMechanic::oilChange(Car carToOil)
{
//we are saying high quality oil is 5*
carToOil.setOilQuality(5);
}

void CarMechanic::resprayCar(Car carToSpray, string sprayColour)
{
carToSpray.setColourOfCar("Green");
cout << "I have spray painted your car " << sprayColour << ". Like you 
wanted." << endl;
string newColour = carToSpray.getColourOfCar();
cout << "The colour of speedster is now " << newColour << endl;
}
```

Car.h:

```
#define CAR_H
#include <string>

class Car
{ // defining the Car class
private: // restricted access, can only access from inside the class.
unsigned fuelLeft; // class member variable.
bool brokenDown = false;
int oilQuality = 0; //Oil quality goes from 1 to 5, with 5 being the highest
std::string colourOfCar = "Unknown";

public: // open access, can access from outside the class (e.g. main).

Car(); // default constructor, has no input parameters.
Car(unsigned); //int, std::string); // another constructor
~Car(); // destructor, called when car objects are destroyed.

short unsigned int fuelSpace;       //irrelevant

void drive();        // irrelevant
bool hasFuel();      //irrelevant
void refuel();       //irrelevant
void breakdownNow(); 
void repairNow();    //irrelevant
bool isBrokenDown();
//functions set and get to change and show private bool brokenDown 
bool getBrokenDown();
void setBrokenDown(bool brokenD);
//functions set and get to change and show private int oilQ
int getOilQuality();
void setOilQuality(int oilQ);
//functions set and get to change and show private string colour
std::string getColourOfCar();
void setColourOfCar(std::string colSet);
};
```

Car.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Car.h"

Car::Car() {}

Car::Car(unsigned startingFuel) {...}

Car::~Car() { } // destructor does nothing.

void Car::drive() {...}

bool Car::hasFuel() {...}

void Car::refuel() {...}

void Car::breakdownNow()
{
brokenDown = true;              //Car is broken
std::cout << "The beakdownNow function has set car to broken." << std::endl;
}

void Car::repairNow()
{
brokenDown = false;             //Car is not broken
std::cout << "The repairNow function has set car to not broken." << 
std::endl;
}

bool Car::isBrokenDown()
{
if (brokenDown == true)
{
    std::cout << "The car is broken." << std::endl;
    return true;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "The car isn't broken." << std::endl;
    return false;
}
}

bool Car::getBrokenDown()
{
return brokenDown;
}
void Car::setBrokenDown(bool brokenD)
{
brokenDown = brokenD;
}

int Car::getOilQuality()
{
return oilQuality;
}
void Car::setOilQuality(int oilQ)
{
oilQuality = oilQ;
}

std::string Car::getColourOfCar()
{
return colourOfCar;
}
void Car::setColourOfCar(std::string colSet)
{
colourOfCar = colSet;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
//Activity 7
myCarObject1.breakdownNow(); //we need the car set to broken so that the mechanic can fix it.

CarMechanic repairMan("Mike");          //Our mechanic's called Mike.

//We need to check if the car is broken.
bool isItBroken = myCarObject1.getBrokenDown();
cout << "isItBroken is set to " << isItBroken << " for true, so it is broken." << endl;

if (isItBroken == true)     //we will only repair if broken.
{
repairMan.repairCar(myCarObject1);      //He will repair the car here
}
//Let us see if he really did fix the car!
isItBroken = myCarObject1.getBrokenDown();
if (isItBroken == false)
{
cout << "Looks like the car is fixed. Since isItBroken is set to " << isItBroken << " for false." << endl;
}
else
{
cout << "The car is still broken for some reason..." << endl;
}


//Activity 8

Car old1930sCar(3); 
//Set the oil quality of car to low.
old1930sCar.setOilQuality(1);
//New object car with low quality oil comes to the mechanic, not good.
//Lets find out what quality of oil it has in main with getOilQuality
int oilQualityOfold1930sCar = old1930sCar.getOilQuality();
cout << "The oil quality of the old 1930's Car is " << oilQualityOfold1930sCar << "*." << endl;

//Lets use function of CarMechanic to replace this bad oil, with 5* oil.
repairMan.oilChange(old1930sCar);

oilQualityOfold1930sCar = old1930sCar.getOilQuality();
cout << "Now we have set the oil quality into the object in the class, it should be 5. It is " << oilQualityOfold1930sCar << "." << endl;

//Let us say that speedster actually wants to change the colour to Green.
repairMan.resprayCar(speedster, "Green");

//Let us confirm the repair man has turned it to green.
string newColour = speedster.getColourOfCar();
cout << "The colour of speedster is now " << newColour << endl;
```

Comment: This isn't homework. This is part of learning material from a teacher. I can ask for help  when I see him, but this isn't until Thursday and there isn't much time to waste...

Comment: Then please use a debugger, or at least create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because of your function definitions in CarMechanic.h and .cpp at:

```
void repairCar(Car &carToFix);
void oilChange(Car carToOil);
void resprayCar(Car carToSpray, string sprayColour);
```

Simply change the defintions to below and also respectively in the cpp files:

```
void repairCar(Car &carToFix);
void oilChange(Car &carToOil);
void resprayCar(Car &carToSpray, string sprayColour);
```

#### Explanation

You said that repairing the car works, changing the oil and spraying the car does not. Repairing Car works because your repairCar() method is taking the Car input paramater by reference using the "**&**". This means that the actual object is "referenced" from physical memory into the function. The other two functions do not pass by reference. In fact, what happens is that within those functions, the Car object is just a copy of the Car object that is passed to the function. This is known as pass by value.

Your oilChange() and resprayCar() changes do not propagate on to the carToOil and carToSpray because the changes you made are on the copy of the Car object. This copy is only local to the function, and when the function completes, these copy objects are simply destroyed.

One way to fix the issue is to pass by reference using "&" as you did in the repairCar() function. Another way is you could return the copy object in the function, i.e.

```
 Car oilChange(Car carToOil);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I probably ignored that one as I thought it was working without the pass by reference before, I must of been wrong.

Comment: No worries! just mark the answer as correct if it helped fix the problem.